# Working with Class, properties and initialization

Tags: objective-c, alloc

I'm working on this assignment I found online (Intermediate App Development Using iOS). I'm stuck on part c and d, don't know exactly what its asking me to do.
I know how to print int (`%i`) and object (`%@`), but `%@` print all data? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Part 6

a) Implement class `A` with properties `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` (`int`, `string`, `int`).
b) New objects are automatically initialized to `1`, `"hello"`, `1`
c) Also provide initializer to any data and constructor (called without `alloc`) to do the same.
d) Make sure `%@` object of `A` will print all data.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
// classA.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject
// Part 6a
@property int a1;
@property NSString *a2;
@property int a3;

-(ClassA *) initWithA1: (int) x andA2: (NSString *) s andA3: (int) y;
@end

//classA.m
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA

-(ClassA *) initWithA1:(int)x andA2:(NSString *)s andA3:(int)y {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.a1 = x;
        self.a2 = s;
        self.a3 = y;
    }
    return self;
}

// part 6b
-(ClassA *) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.a1 = 0;
        self.a2 =@"hello";
        self.a3 = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: You say "part c, part d" etc, but you don't provide a link to the assignment.

Comment: Its included in the description. I made it more visible with use of white space.

Comment: I still don't see it?!?

Comment: Checkout examples how to override `-description` (that's the `d` part)

Comment: Right below my question, it says Part 6 and labeled a b c d?

Comment: @trojanfoe just googled that course assignment and found http://www.outreach.hawaii.edu/pnm/programs/2011/EVENT-L11701.asp based on the assumption this is it, this is part of a course and would come under homework. Which as you know we don't do.

Comment: I didn't even used to do my own homework, let alone others...

Comment: @trojanfoe haha same. `Christopher Palmer` please provide the link as requested to this assignment so we can determine whether this is a piece of homework or not as we don't do users homework for them because you will not learn anything.

Comment: @Sulthan so something like this `-(NSString *)description {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@", self.a1, self.a2, self.a3];
}`

Comment: @Popeye: Please note that there is no general rule against homework questions. Of course they should follow the guidelines from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. More about homework questions here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to part "b" of your question:

As a general rule, only 1 initializer should be doing the "real" work. This is often referred to as the *designated initializer*. So, your `init` method should probably read something like:

```
- (id) init
{
    return [self initWithA1:1 andA2:@"hello" andA3:1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So what I did is not wrong, but better way is what you suggested?

Comment: If by saying 'not wrong' we can mean that the code works for you in this situation, then I'll go with that. Designated initializers is a generally accepted design pattern in Obj-C and Apple frameworks. The `init` method is the default (users can always call alloc/init on any object and expect to get something useful) -- it is your job to make sure that your object is _always_ initialized properly. The easiest way to guarantee that is the designated initializer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As @orbitor wrote, your class should have one designated initialiser.

> So, your `init` method should probably read something like:

```
- (id) init
{
    return [self initWithA1:1 andA2:@"hello" andA3:1];
}
```

In order to print all object you should implement custom `description` method:

```
- (NSString *) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a1 = %d, a2 = %@, a3 = %d", self.a1, self.a2, self.a3];;
}
```

According to c: 
Class method `new` just calls `alloc` and `init` methods so you should only make sure that you wrote properly all initialisers.